# macOS under M1, cannot find library

Tags: memory, process, libraries, macos

I'm looking for the following dylib file which is included from process `loginwindow`.

If I run `vmmap` to inspect `loginwindow` while it's up and running I get :

``` user@mycomp / % sudo vmmap -I ``pgrep loginwindow`` | grep libIASUnifiedProgress.dylib ```

```
__TEXT                      1c7566000-1c756e000    [   32K    32K     0K     0K] r-x/r-x SM=COW          /usr/lib/libIASUnifiedProgress.dylib
__DATA_CONST                1fdd05628-1fdd06438    [  3600   3600     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/libIASUnifiedProgress.dylib
__DATA                      200ff1f18-200ff27b0    [  2200   2200     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/libIASUnifiedProgress.dylib
__AUTH_CONST                207d4b260-207d4c008    [  3496   3496     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/libIASUnifiedProgress.dylib
__OBJC_CONST                207d4c008-207d4c368    [   864    864     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/libIASUnifiedProgress.dylib
__DATA_DIRTY                20a5b9250-20a5b9460    [   528    528    528     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /usr/lib/libIASUnifiedProgress.dylib
```

however, the file doesn't appear to be there ... I'm guessing it's some new trick made by Apple, perhaps do you know how can I find it anyway ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On ARM macOS, like on iOS, most of the common dylibs are no longer shipped as separate files, but are bundled into the [dyld shared cache](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Dyld_shared_cache). You can usually find the caches in `/System/Library/dyld/`.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help. So, In this case, do you know where can I find the this bundle backed static file ? and after I've found it, would I expect it to be encrypted ?

Comment: @Zohar81 added the location. It's not encrypted but extracting dylibs from it is not trivial since it's optimized for code and data sharing

Comment: Do you think that I can link against this library (libIASUnifiedProgress.dylib) from my own project ? I see that in Xcode it's existed as tbd under :  `./Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libIASUnifiedProgress.tbd`

Comment: Yes, linking against the .tbd should work.